# A Counryman line is an Aronszajn line.

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

To see that every countryman line is Aronszajn line, it suffices to show that $\omega_1$, $\omega_1^*=(\omega_1,\ni)$ and uncountable separable liner order are not a Countryman line. (This is because that the subset of a Countryman line is also a Countryman line.)

**I cannot prove that every uncountable separable linear order is not a Countryman line.
How to prove this.**

The proof of that $\omega_1$ is not a Countryman line is :

Assume that there are countably many linear orders $C_n\subset\omega_1\times\omega_1$ with $\cup\{C_n|n\in\omega_1\}=\omega_1\times\omega_1$. For every $\alpha\in\omega_1$ choose $n_\alpha$ such as $D_\alpha=\{y\in\omega_1|(x,y)\in C_{n_\alpha}\}$ is uncounable. Then there are $\alpha\in\beta\in\omega_1$ such that $n_\alpha=n_\beta$ (by the Pigeonhole principle). Fix arbitrary $\delta\in\omega_1$ such as $(\beta,\delta)\in C_{n_\alpha}$. Then since $C_{n_\alpha}$ is uncountable, there is $\gamma$ such that $\delta\in\gamma$ and $(\alpha,\gamma)\in C_{n_\alpha}$. This shows that there is incompatible pair $(\alpha,\gamma)$ and $(\beta,\delta)$ in $C_{n_\alpha}=C_{n_\beta}$, a contradiction.

**Note.** Following are definition of Aronszajn line and Countryman line:

Aronszajn line is an uncountable line which does not possess a sublinear order which isomorphic to $\omega_1$, $\omega_1^*$ or an uncountable linear order.

Countryman line ,(L,<_L), is a line such that there are countably many sublinear orders $C_n\subset L\times L$ such that $\cup\{C_n|n\in\omega\}=L\times L$. Where the order on $L\times L$ is given by $(a,b)<_L(c,d)$ provided that "$a\leq_Lc$ and $b\leq_Ld$" and "$\neg(a=c\land b=d)$".

Comment: The title and the boldfaced text ask very different questions.

Comment: Thanks for telling me. The statement in text is correct.

Comment: Your definition of an Aronszajn line can't be correct. Just remove a point, or cut the order somewhere and take whichever ray is uncountable.

Comment: Can you prove that $\Bbb R$ is not Countryman?

Comment: To see that the real numbers is not a Countryman line, for every $x\in\mathbb R$, choose $n$ such as $(x,-x)\in C_n$. Then there are distinct $x,y$ such that both $(x,-x)$ and $(y,-y)$ are in the same $C_n$, this contrary that $C_n$ is a totally ordered set.

Comment: Great. Now use that to prove that no uncountable subset of the reals is Countryman. Then finally, every separable linear order embeds into the reals.

Comment: I completely understand. The former is by joining the integers and mimic the of the case reals is not a Countryman line. The later derived from that the countable dense linear order with no endpoints is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$.

Thank you.

Comment: "The former" is the proof that assume that there is an uncountable subset which is Countryman.